# Why do I get this error? TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying use the geoip2 library to get the location of an ip address, but I keep getting a Type error.

The code used to work before, not sure what happened.

```
@client.command(name="iplocation")
async def ip_location(*,ip):
    try:
        reader = geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
        response = reader.city(ip)

        await client.say("Country: " + response.country.iso_code)
        await client.say("City: " + response.subdivisions.most_specific.name)
        await client.say("Postal Code: " + response.postal.code)
        await client.say("Latitude: " + str(response.location.latitude))
        await client.say("Longitude: " + str(response.location.longitude))
        reader.close()
     except geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError:
         await client.say("The Address: " + ip + " Is not in the database")
     except ValueError:
         await client.say(ip + " Does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address.")
```

I expect

Country: US
City: New York
Postal Code: 10453 
Latitude: 1.2931
Longitude: 103.8558

This is just an example.

my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c0deninja/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "discordbot2.py", line 116, in ip_location
    await client.say("City: " + response.subdivisions.most_specific.name)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

Comment: What is the exact error with trace? It's probably the country, postal code, or city being `None` though. You need to wrap those in `str`, or figure out why they're `None`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate edited the post to show the error message, I tried to wrap them with str(), the code works but then i get None as the output for both City and postal code.

Comment: Then the response data is invalid/incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data set you are pulling data from must be using None as a type when there is no city set. In this case the error message is a great tip. You'll have to either allow it to use None as a string by doing the conversion you said works, or test for None, and use a blank string in place of an actual city name.

This error is likely to happen in any instance where there is not a string set in the whatever data set you're working with.

```
File "discordbot2.py", line 116, in ip_location
    await client.say("City: " + response.subdivisions.most_specific.name)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```